# How to highlight proper bar in vega based on columns?

Tags: vega

So I have a basic Vega bar chart [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/vega/jdarling/4998499924300ef8d91f6f87259d5c20/6ef585a49dc92cca474571dafadb282a1ee59625/spec.json) with data with large differences in size.  Currently you have to have the mouse over the top of the actual bar(s) in order to get a tooltip or highlight the bars.  I'm trying to figure out how to highlight the appropriate bar based on mouse position above the bar.  As an example if I am directly above (in the same column) the Facebook bar I would like it to highlight and show the appropriate tooltip.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So the only way I can find to do this is to use an opaque bar with a band of 1.  This basically creates a "fake" transparent bar that is then used for the mouseover and mouseout events.

Working chart [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/vega/jdarling/4998499924300ef8d91f6f87259d5c20/34946570316cf3fe3d8bd35188d6ee465ef19d78/spec.json)